# Is there a possibilty to close all code breaks in R script at once?

Tags: r, rstudio

After searching through all kinds of "how to structure code"-threads and not finding an answer to my question I hope there is one existing though. When structuring my code I tend to use a lot of code breaks (comments ending with "####") or sections to make navigating easier (I recently found the workflow package [strcode](https://lorenzwalthert.netlify.com/posts/strcode1/) for RStudio and find it very helpful for that) but unluckily after reopening a structured script I still have the issue of having to close all breaks manually (which is pretty annoying even for a few breaks).

Is there any possibility existing to tell RStudio to close (or open) all breaks in a script at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RStudio this works:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> : close all breaks

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> : open all breaks

---

Also useful, I think

<kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> : insert a break